# elasticsearch - confused on how to searching items that a field contains string

Tags: elasticsearch

This query is returning fine only one item "steve_jobs".

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "name":"steve_jobs"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, now I want to get all people with name prefix `steve_`. So I try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "name": "steve_"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is returning nothing. Why?

I'm confused about when to use term query / term filter / terms filter / querystring query.

Comment: Hey did my answer help you? Can you comment on that please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [Prefix Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html).

If you are indexing your document like so:

```
POST /testing_nested_query/class/
{
    "name": "my name is steve_jobs"
}
```

And you are using the default analyzer, then the problem is that the term `steve_jobs` will be indexed as one term. So your Term Query will never be able to find any docs matching the term `steve` as there is no term like in the index. Prefix Query helps you solve your problem by searching for a prefix in all the indexed terms.

You can solve the same problem by making your custom analyzers (read [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) and [this](http://www.smashew.com/2013/07/25/elasticsearch-custom-analyzer/)) so that `steve_jobs` is stored as `steve` and `jobs`.